# Function is called but it not shows error for repassword validation. Function is called by onBlur event

Tags: javascript

```
function repasswordvalid()
{
    var cpassword = document.registration.repassword.value;
    var passwordchk = document.registration.password.value;

    if((passwordchk != cpassword) && cpassword == "")
    {
        alert("Cofirm password not matched..!!");
        document.getElementById('repassword1').innerHTML = "The password is required.";
        document.getElementById('repassword1').focus(); 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('repassword1').innerHTML = "";  
    }
}
```

Here I am checking for confirm password validation onBlur event. All fields are working but here i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an **or** in your condition not an **and**, since the cpassword will have to be blank and both field mismatched for the alert to trigger

```
if((passwordchk != cpassword) || cpassword == "")
```